# How to return dataframe to Shiny app from Modal Dialog in Shiny module?

Tags: r, shinyapps, shinymodules

I'm working on the large shiny app and I need to show a modal dialog and allow to perform some arithmetics operations in there, and when it is closed, it should return the data modified according to with de arithmetics to update data in the data table output. Furthermore, if the new dataset is selected, it should clear the fields, otherwise, if the modal is open again, should show the field loaded previously.
Since my app is very large, I want to create a modular code but when I call de module from bt_show_modal button in observeEvent, it does not do anything.

**I've build the app in ui.r and server.r structure and works fine!**
This is app code:

```
# APP CODE WITHOUT MODULE
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sortable)

doSum <- function(data, col1, col2, col_result) {
  data[col_result] <- data[, col1] + data[, col2] # sum columns
  return(data)
}
dataSet1 <- data.frame(
    country = c("EEUU", "Italy", "Spain", "France"),
    sales1 = c(500, 200, 1000, 1800),
    sales2 = c(900, 100, 200, 1200))
dataSet2 <-  data.frame(
    city = c("Nwe York", "Rome", "Madrid", "Paris"),
    sales1 = c(500, 200, 1000, 1800),
    sales2 = c(900, 100, 200, 1200))  
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput(inputId =  "datasets",label = "Datasets",
                choices = c("Countries", "Cities"),selected = "Countries"),
    actionButton("bt_show_modal", "Show modal")),
  dataTableOutput("preview1")
)    
server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(df_wd = NULL)
  values <- reactiveValues(g_l_oper1 = NULL)
  values <- reactiveValues(g_l_oper2 = NULL)
  modalReactive <- reactive({
    modalDialog(
      column(width = 6,
             fluidRow(rank_list(text = "Fields",
                 labels = names(values$df_wd),
                 input_id = "l_source",
                 options = sortable_options(group = "list_group")))),
      column(width = 6,
        fluidRow(rank_list(text = "Variable 1",
            labels = values$g_l_oper1,
            input_id = "l_oper1",
            options = sortable_options(group = "list_group"))),
        fluidRow(rank_list(text = "Variable 2",
            labels = values$g_l_oper2,
            input_id = "l_oper2",
            options = sortable_options(group = "list_group")))),
      actionButton("btExecute", "Execute")
    )
  })      
  resetReactiveValues <- function() {
    values$df_wd <- NULL
    values$g_l_oper1 <- NULL
    values$g_l_oper2 <- NULL
  }      
  workData <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(values$df_wd))
      values$df_wd
    else
      if (input$datasets == "Countries")
        values$df_wd <- dataSet1
      else
        values$df_wd <- dataSet2
  })    
  observeEvent(input$bt_show_modal, {
    showModal(modalReactive())
  })      
  observeEvent(input$btExecute, {
    values$df_wd <- doSum(workData(), input$l_oper1, input$l_oper2, "col_sum")
    values$g_l_oper1 <- input$l_oper1
    values$g_l_oper2 <- input$l_oper2
    removeModal()
  })      
  observeEvent(input$datasets, {
    resetReactiveValues()
  })      
  output$preview1 <- renderDataTable({
    df <- workData()
    req(df)
    datatable(df)
  })
}    
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**AND THIS IS THE MODULE IMPLEMEMTATION:**

```
# MODULE CODE
doSum <- function(data, col1, col2, col_result) {
  data[col_result] <- data[, col1] + data[, col2] # sum columns
  return(data)
}    
modalUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(uiOutput(ns("sortable_object")))
}

modalServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 values <- reactiveValues(df_wd = NULL)
                 values <- reactiveValues(v_operand1 = NULL)
                 values <- reactiveValues(v_operand2 = NULL)
                 
                 modalReactive <- reactive({
                   values$df_wd = data # Save parameter in reative global variable
                   ns <- session$ns # Name space
                   modalDialog(
                     column(width = 6,
                            fluidRow(rank_list(text = "Fields",
                                               labels = names(values$df_wd),
                                               input_id = ns("l_source"),
                                               options = sortable_options(group = "list_group")))),
                     column(width = 6,
                            fluidRow(rank_list(text = "Variable 1",
                                               labels = values$v_operand1,
                                               input_id = ns("l_oper1"),
                                               options = sortable_options(group = "list_group"))),
                            fluidRow(rank_list(text = "Variable 2",
                                               labels = values$v_operand2,
                                               input_id = ns("l_oper2"),
                                               options = sortable_options(group = "list_group")))),
                     actionButton(ns("btExecute"), "Execute")
                   )
                 })
                 
                 observe({
                   req(values$df_wd)
                   showModal(modalReactive())
                 })
                 
                 observeEvent(input$btExecute, {
                     print("Execute")
                     values$df_wd <- doSum(values$df_wd,input$l_oper1,input$l_oper2,"col_sum")
                     values$v_operand1 <- input$l_oper1
                     values$v_operand2 <- input$l_oper2
                     removeModal()
                   })
                 return(reactive(values$df_wd)) # Dataframe with the new col "col_sum"
               })
}
# APP CODE
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sortable)

dataSet1 <- data.frame(
  country = c("EEUU", "Italy", "Spain", "France"),
  sales1 = c(3500, 2100, 2000, 1500),
  sales2 = c(900, 100, 200, 1200))
dataSet2 <-  data.frame(
  city = c("Nwe York", "Rome", "Madrid", "Paris"),
  sales1 = c(500, 200, 1000, 1800),
  sales2 = c(700, 300, 500, 1100))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    selectInput(inputId =  "datasets",label = "Datasets",
                choices = c("Countries", "Cities"),selected = "Countries"),
    actionButton("bt_show_modal", "Show modal")),
  dataTableOutput("preview1"),
  modalUI("modal_module")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues(df_wd = NULL)
  workData <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(values$df_wd))
      values$df_wd
    else
      if (input$datasets == "Countries")
        values$df_wd <- dataSet1
      else
        values$df_wd <- dataSet2
  })
  
  modalReactive <- modalServer("modal_module", reactive(values$df_wd)) # Call the module
  
  observeEvent(input$bt_show_modal, {
    values$df_wd  <- modalReactive()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$datasets, {
    values$df_wd <- NULL # Reset variable
  })
  
  output$preview1 <- renderDataTable({
    df <- workData()
    req(df)
    datatable(df)
  })
}    
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please be cognizant that you are asking others to pour thru your code and find your errors. It would be helpful if you could pair the code down to the smallest set of commands. Also, It is common/helpful to display an example that others can test. Thank you

Comment: @oaxacamatt thanks for your feedback.
According with your suggest, I've do the code more compact and simple as possible. First code run ok and that is the behavior expected.